# Are these VirtualHost settings workable with Django?

Tags: django, apache, virtualhost

I'm deploying a Django app on a client's website and do not have direct access to the httpd.conf files. Site support has created the following for me but there does not seem to be any combination of STATIC_ROOT and STATIC_URL that I can get to work with this. Is it even possible?

NOTE: the Django/Python pages are being served just fine on subdomain.mywebsite.com--I'm only missing the static files. (Sorry to obfuscate the URLs and IPs...client is very private.)

UPDATE 1 (trailing slashes removed -- still doesn't work)

```
NameVirtualHost ##.###.###.#

<VirtualHost ##.###.###.#>
DocumentRoot /home/httpd/html/subdomain.mywebsite.com/public_html
ScriptAlias /cgi-bin /home/httpd/html/subdomain.mywebsite.com/cgi-bin
ServerName www.subdomain.mywebsite.com
CustomLog /home/httpd/logs/subdomain.mywebsite.com_access_log combined
ServerAlias subdomain.mywebsite.com

Alias /static/ /home/httpd/html/subdomain.mywebsite.com/public_html/static/
 <Directory /home/httpd/html/subdomain.mywebsite.com/public_html/>
    allow from all
</Directory>


<Directory /home/httpd/html/subdomain.mywebsite.com/public_html/>
    <Files wsgi.py>
        allow from all
    </Files>
</Directory>

ProxyPreserveHost On
ProxyPass / http://127.0.0.1:8000/
ProxyPassReverse / http://127.0.0.1:8000/

</VirtualHost>
```

And here's what's in my settings.py file

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = '/home/httpd/html/notices.removeyourcontent.com/public_html'
```

I've also tried:

```
STATIC_ROOT = '/home/httpd/html/notices.removeyourcontent.com/public_html/static'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just remove the slash after static, I had same issue, turns out extra slash after static was issue.

```
Alias /static /home/httpd/html/subdomain.mywebsite.com/public_html/static/
```

Also as mentioned by OP in comments, removing ProxyPass helped.

```
ProxyPass / http://127.0.0.1:8000/
```

Comment: Thanks for that suggestion. Trying that now... initially removed BOTH trailing slashes and that is not what you suggested.

Comment: Your suggestion probably helped, but the ProxyPass line was still preventing it from working. Someone on the host-side eventually realized that and removed that line. Thank you again for the suggestion!

Comment: Hi @evan, Please accept the answer if you feel like it might have help. I'll also update the ProxyPass thing in answer so others can see.